# Open infoWindow using external link outside of Google map api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I am currently using the Google map JS api to show the location of a number of locations.

For each of these locations I have an infoWindow set, I am wanting to open these infoWindows from an external link. I have found a number of solutions on here however they don't seem to relate to my code (taken from the Google API guides).

This is my JS code:

```
function initMap() {
    var home = {lat: 54.300213, lng: -0.4483022};

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        scrollwheel: false,
        center: home
    });

    // Create an array of alphabetical characters used to label the markers.
    var labels  = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    var infoWin = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    // Add some markers to the map.
    // Note: The code uses the JavaScript Array.prototype.map() method to
    // create an array of markers based on a given "locations" array.
    // The map() method here has nothing to do with the Google Maps API.
    var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            label: labels[i % labels.length]
        })
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker[id], 'click', function(evt) {
            infoWin.setContent(location.info);
            infoWin.open(map, marker);
        });
        return marker;
    });

    // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
        {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
}

var locations = [
    ['London Eye, London', 51.503454,-0.119562],
    ['Palace of Westminster, London', 51.499633,-0.124755]
];
```

I have 2 links in my html that I want to use to open the info windows of each location (marker). I also intend adding more markers along with more html links. These Links are on the same page as my map.

Comment: What does the HTML that you want to open these infowindows from look like? Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: The posted code doesn't work.  I get javascript errors: `InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number` and `Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined`.  Please provide a [mcve] (emphasis on **verifiable**)

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

I have made changes and the code is now working on here [link](https://bettondesignwork.co.uk/map/map.html)

I have basic links, and the link to the other question is one that I have already tried and does not seem to relate to my code (taken from the Google API guides).